# How to call a function when Polymer paper-input is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I've got a polymer app that takes a text input (ID) and returns a "yes" or "no" based on whether the ID is in a list or not. Ideally, a user can press enter or click a "lookup" button, and the "search for ID" function will get called.

Can I do this without using a form?
If I use a form, can I do this without making a post/put/get request? The data is all stored in a property (array) of the element.

```
<dom-module id="demo-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-card heading="Search for ID">
      <div class="card-content">
        <paper-input id="input" always-float-label label="ID"</paper-input>
      </div>
    </paper-card>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'demo-app',

      properties: {
        myIds: {
          type: Array,
          value: ['testID1', 'testID2'],
        },
        inputObj: {
          type: Object,
          value: function(){
            return this.$.input;
          }
        },
        userInput: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
      onEnter: function(){
        if(this.myIds.includes(this.userInput)) {
          console.log(this.userInput);
        }
      },

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've seen similar questions with related answers - such as 1) using iron-a11y-keys to listen for keys="enter" and 2) making a function called "checkForEnter" like if (e.keyCode === 13) and adding on-keydown="checkForEnter" to the paper-input element attributes. Even some where I use a form and override the default form submission. Wondering if there is a "best practices" way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for Polymer is to "Use The Platform", and in this case HTML (a button's default behavior is to submit its form) & a bit of JavaScript will work.

Specifically, wrap your input in a form and add a button:

```
<form id="demoAppForm">
  <paper-card heading="Search for ID">
    <div class="card-content">
      <paper-input id="input" always-float-label label="ID"</paper-input>
    </div>
    <button>Lookup</button>
  </paper-card>
<form>
```

And then set up an event listener for when the form is submitted, `preventDefault` on that event (so it won't do a GET request), and do what you want with the data by adding these functions to your `Polymer({...})` call:

```
attached: function() {
  this.listen(this.$.demoAppForm, 'submit', 'onSubmit');
},

onSubmit: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Lookup this:', this.$.input.value);
},
```

Make sure you remove the event listener too when the element is detached:

```
detached: function() {
  this.unlisten(this.$.demoAppForm, 'submit', 'onSubmit');
},
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work simply by adding an on-change="inputHandler" - for some reason this only gets triggered when I hit enter. If I bind anything to the value, for example have a <p> {{userInput}} was entered </p> the value will update in real time - but the function only runs when I hit enter. I also set the value to "value="{{userInput::input}}" although I'm not sure what the "::input" part does - do you know?
Anyhow I will use your code, thank you for showing me how this is done!